# Can't install python package available on github

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, github, pip

I am trying to install a python package that is available on github, but am unsure how to do so. This is the package: https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.

Could someone please provide me clear and step-by-step instructions on how to do this installation? None of the current answers are clear enough for me. I have tried the following command prompt command, but it is not working. I have git installed.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.git
```

Error:

```
Cloning https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.git to c:\users\haris\appdata\local\temp\pip-ocsu8r-build
Error [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.git c:\users\haris\appdata\local\temp\pip-ocsu8r-build
Cannot find command 'git'
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Install `git`?

Comment: > My goal is to install a python package that is available on github < What are you talking about?

Comment: If you want to clone some repository from github, you should install git from you package manager(apt for example) and type `git clone repository_address`

Comment: If you mean you want to use pip to install a pip that's available on github, like installing an npm that's available on github, [the issue for that is still open](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3610). So, you can't. If you mean soemthing else...I don't know.

Comment: Clarifying edits later, you probably want this https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ or this https://www.gitkraken.com/

Answer (score 3):

git isn't installed via pip. It's a regular package that you'll want to install by doing `apt install git`, most likely as root.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to install the package outside of pip since it’s not a python package. `Conda install` will work if you have anaconda or miniconda , or `apt get install` if you’re on a Linux system. Once you have git, run `got clone package_name` after navigating to the desired directory and you should be good to go.